# Email Server Functionality with Java Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications, integration, mail-server

I have a web application which has several users and each user will have some username which will be unique.

What I want is every registered user get a unique email id like when user xyz registers he gets xyz@domain.com.

This user registers using our web application developed in java, struts2, hibernate etc.

I will need a mail server to do this that I understood, but I do not want to write a mail server application but just talk to that application with some api calls or something.

I am evaluation hmail serve which is java based open source solution, any other solution that will address this particular usecase.

I want my application to act like the front end to this some like any other email service provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Mail Enable](http://www.mailenable.com).

Comment: Looking for an open-source application. Any other?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Spring's email library: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mail.html

Comment: Yes. This is to send mail but not creating email accounts or act like an mail server!